# URL Query String to check database on Window Load

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating a mobile guest list for a party that I'm having in a few months.  All of the invites that I am handing out will have a custom QR Code on them, embedding their first and last name.  When they get to the party, they check in with me, I scan their QR Code and throw them into a database.

I have the core elements working where the custom QR Code with the embedded query strings for first and last names pre-populate a set of text inputs for the first and last names, you fill in some other information, click submit and BANG, you're in the database.

I would like to add some extra functionality that checks the database that someone has already checked in, to prevent party crashers.

What code would I need to write to allow, onWindowLoad, the first and last name query strings to be checked against the database to see if entries containing those already exist?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just do an AJAX call with a select... SELECT * FROM people where f_name = "$first_input" AND l_name = "$last_input";  If you return results... let them know.

Comment: @wes How would I word the Ajax Call? type: "GET", url: "guestlist.php", data: dataString?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call with a select.  Make it easy on yourself, use jQuery.  Here are some examples:

[Ajax Examples with jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/)